# JavaScript, Check a Radio Button on Load Depending on the End of URL

Tags: javascript, url, radio-button, lastindexof

I am clutching at straws a little bit here, I want to do as the title says, when the page loads I would really love some javascript to fire off some code that checks the url, and reads the end of it. I then want to have an 'if' that says (URL ends with =en?check this radio:do nothing). the code I have attempting at fitting already is messy at best but I will show you to help you understand my lack of ability and to better explain my query:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var url = window.location.href;
    var lastPart = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if (lastPart === "=en") {
        radiobtn = document.getElementById("123456789");
        radiobtn.checked = true;
    }
};
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: what does console.log( lastPart ); give..?

Comment: it gives me the last 29 digits of the URL, I think I miraculously have actually done it correctly, but i need to change the lastindexof?

Comment: "it gives me the last 29 digits of the URL..", but you're checking it against "=en" which would never satisfy the condition, could you share the example url you are checking for...?

Comment: My problem was a stupid one sorry, I wasnt getting the last three digits from the url, I was grabbing everything after the '/' which was 29  chars, I have changed it so now it only gets everything after 'language' which is =en or =ko etc... sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a serious lack of understanding of the code of the code I was attempting to use.

```
var lastPart = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

I didnt realise that this was reading everything after the char '/'. After changing it to '=' it worked perfectly!

Sorry community!